# Code to escape characters does not replace '

Tags: php, escaping

I'm having trouble pre-fixing the single quote `'` character. I'm trying to make a simple injection prevention function ...

```
function injectionProtect($string) {
    $notallowed = array('\'','"','\\');
    $letters=str_split($string);
    foreach($letters as $key => $value) {
        if (array_search($value,$notallowed)>=1) {
            $letters[$key]='\\' . $value;
        }
    }
    $string=implode("",$letters);
    return $string;
}
```

It works for the `\` and `"` characters, but not the `'` character ... Any one know whats going wrong?

I've tried typing the `'` as `'\''` and `"'"` but neither works, it just still outputs it as `'`

Comment: Do not do a simple injection protection as it is futile, either do it a way that works, or don't do it at all. Are you trying to protect against SQL injection? use binder, HTML injection? use htmlescape(..)

Comment: Don't do this. Writing your own quoting function is hard. Use the specific escaping functions available from your target environment. It'll be FAR safe, and your version is hackable/bypassable in so many ways it's not even funny.

Comment: why you are not using stripslashes()?

Comment: Making a "simple injection prevention function" is inherently impossible, since the problem is not "simple". At least not as simple as you think it is.

Comment: :D ... I am aware there are already escaping functions out there, it's just a little project I'm working on, but can anyone see why it's not working for the ' character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do **not** use this function to prevent SQL injection. It is not easy to create a function that can account for all possible cases of SQL injection. The correct way would be to use MySQLi / PDO with prepared statements.

Now, to answer your question:

[`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, `FALSE` otherwise. Currently, you're checking if the return value is `>=1`. The single quote character is the `0th` index in your array, so the code inside your `if` block will not get executed when the `$value` is `'`.

To know if any of the array values in `$notallowed` exists in `$value`, you could simply check if the return value is `FALSE` or not:

```
if (array_search($value,$notallowed) !== FALSE) {
    $letters[$key]='\\' . $value;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I thought it returned TRUE if it was found in the array :D Many thanks :D ... And yeah, I'm not going to be using this on any live site Lol

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of SQL injection functions exist.  No need to reinvent the wheel.